# How I can compare size of filename batch

Tags: batch-file

How I can compare size of file-name in batch?

example my folder:

```
2011-01-22_fas_alex      55kb

2011-01-22-sup_alex      10kb

2015-01-22_fas_marc       45kb

2015-01-22-sup_marc       10kb

The result one: (55/10)kb = 5.5

The result two: 45/10)kb = 4.5
```

The format of the files are:!

```
<Date> <fas  or sup> <Name
```

You see, the date and the name must be the same.

Comment: so fas is with underscore and sup is with dash?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%# in (????-??-??-sup_*) do (
  set file=%%#
  set name=!file:~15!
  set date=!file:~0,10!
  set size1=%%~z#
  for %%$ in ("!date!_fas_!name!") do set size2=%%~z$ 
  echo !name! - [!size1!/!size2!]
)
```

(and not totally sure what the question is)